# How to insert_many with txMongo avoiding duplicated keys?

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo-3.x

I'm trying to insert a list of documents in MongoDB, each document has the field "_id". So when I send a list like this

```
[{"_id":"2"}, {"_id":"1"}, {"_id":"3"}]
```

And at least one of the _id's is already in the DB, it shows an `pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError`.

I need to use the `insert_many` or any similar function and when I use it, it returns me a list with the not-inserted id's or the inserted ones.

I've seen that `insert_many` inserts one by one, and when it finds the exception, it stops and doesn't insert the rest of the documents.

Do you know any alternative of txMongo that I can use that insert all the documents it can and return me those who couldn't be inserted?

I don't want to insert one by one 'cause I possibly send a huge list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you :

[Performing Unordered Insert in MongoDB using PyMongo](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many)

Just set the `unordered` attribute to false. Same can be seen [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#perform-an-unordered-insert)