# insert_many preventing duplication on data without _id

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

i retrieve a `list` of `dict` which i try to insert in the database with `self.db.bugzilla.insert_many(docs)`. However the documents looks to get double with each execution.

I haven't created indexes as it was suggested in other solutions to prevent publications. None of the solutions from [mongodb: insert if not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801008/mongodb-insert-if-not-exists) [Insert_many dataframe into MongoDB and skipping duplicates issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74662695/insert-many-dataframe-into-mongodb-and-skipping-duplicates-issues) and [How to insert_many with txMongo avoiding duplicated keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429555/how-to-insert-many-with-txmongo-avoiding-duplicated-keys) seems to fit in my case.

I read the [documentation](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) too but i still cant figure it out. I have already tried with `insert_one` and `update_many`. Can maybe someone help?

An example of the data looks like this

```json
[
  {
    "assigned_to": "test@email.com",
    "creation_time": "20211208T14:48:10",
    "id": 1193534,
    "assigned_to_detail": {
      "email": "test@email.com",
      "id": 52497,
      "real_name": "john John",
      "name": "test@email.com"
    },
    "resolution": "FIXED",
    "status": "RESOLVED"
  },
  // {...},
  // ...
]
```

Then, once i run the script a few times i can see the duplicated entries using `db.bugzilla.find({assigned_to: 'test@email.com'})`. The only difference is the added *_id*.

Comment: you should clarify better desired behavior, what do you want to do with duplicated records?

Comment: Perhaps if you show (portions of) example `dict`'s (documents), and how you identify duplicate documents, someone may be able to show a working MongoDB operation to update your collection.

Comment: description updated.

Comment: @dododo when the dictionary is exactly the same i dont want them to be inserted. just insert the ones that have id which is not in the db. ofc i will have to update an existing one when one of the fields have changed later on.

Comment: _"when the dictionary is exactly the same"_  Duplicate records depend on every field, not just on, say, `"id"`?

Comment: As such {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2'} should not be added again. but when is added mongo add an _id. i guess thats why creates a  new document, right? i cant see how can i prevent that

Comment: Depending on exactly what is considered a duplicate document, you could perform an update with an `upsert` option.